# azure interactive shell history

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am wondering if there is a command that gives me history of the commands I've used inside azure interactive shell. Well, I can press up and down arrow to circle through my recent commands, but I'd like to see them all. Just to clarify: I know how to use "history" in the bash, with grep and so forth; I am running Linux Subsystem on Windows.

Comment: Whoever disliked, why? Obviously when i run commands Not in interactive shell, i can use "history", but what do I use inside the "az interactive" shell?

Comment: Currently, azure cli does not support this. If you use bash shell, you could use `history` to check history command.

Comment: thank you. So that dislike is totally unjustified. Please add "history" command to azure interactive shell. I use the shell a lot.

Comment: You could use `history|grep az`. The command only list az command.

Comment: history|grep az does not help. See below. Thanks for your time though so I will upvote. If you downvoted me, please remove it -- totally unjustified downvote.

Comment: Hi, I don't down vote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Azure Cli 2.0 does not support this. If you use bash shell, you could use command `history` to check history command. Like below:

```
history| grep az|grep -v "grep"
```

Also, your suggestion is a good idea, you could give feedback to developer with command `az feedback`.

Comment: hi Walter. Thanks for your reply again. The command you've provided is quite familiar to me -- however it does not show the az commands ran in the "az interactive" shell. As I've mentioned above, please add "history" command for the interactive shell. I think it can be useful, specially since I am writing technical documentation and tutorials and would love to quickly just copy/paste my interactive shell's history. Thanks!

Comment: You could give a feedback to Azure CLI developer.  `az feedback`. I think it is a good idea.

Comment: Awesome suggestion. Will do that! Have a good day.

Comment: I accepted since you've answered my question. The answer was-- There is none currently available.